# set Custom field in rt software(Ticketing System) with email from Sharepoint

Tags: email, sharepoint, rt

I want set Custom Field in request Tracker system with email from Sharepoint. I use Sharepoint Designer for sending email. but I Cant. write this in first line of email:

```
cf.{QM-Category of work}:Permission
```

other User with sending email can set cf.

Can anybody help me?
Tnx

> Use this version of RT :  RT 4.2.8 Copyright 1996-2014 Best Practical Solutions

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using [Command by mail](http://search.cpan.org/~bps/RT-Extension-CommandByMail/lib/RT/Extension/CommandByMail.pm) extension to do that. Note that the commands are executed only when user sending the mail has the proper authorization. So give your Sharepoint user, represented by email address, the appropriate rights for the target queue.